# Splitting lemma for many (at least 3) components

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

I am interested in such version of [splitting lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_lemma):

So given short exact sequence

$\hskip2.5in$ [image]

we have three equivalent statements:

- short exact sequence is right split, i.e there is map $t: B\to A$ such that $tq$ is the identity on $A$.
- short exact sequence is left split, i.e there is map $u: C\to B$ such that $ru$ is the identity on $C$.

$\hskip2.5in$[image]

- There exists an isomorphism from $B$ to $A\oplus C$ such that $q$ and $r$ correspond to natural inclusion and projection respectively. (We may assume here that we are in some fixed abelian category and now the last statement means that $B$ is isomorphic to the [biproduct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biproduct) of $A$ and $C$).

> Can you see any nice looking modification of splitting lemma so that the statement "$B$ is isomorphic to direct sum of $B_1,\dots,B_n$" would be one of the equivalent conditions?

The point is that I like to do the following things:

Start with surjective mapping $r:B\to C,$ set $A=\ker r$ and $q:A\hookrightarrow B$ to be an inclusion. Then for obtained exact sequence
$$0\to A\hookrightarrow B \stackrel{r}\to C\to 0$$
I try to find left splitting $u:C\to B.$ If I succeed I have second projection $t:B\to A$ given by $$t=I_B-ru.$$
The advantage of this approach is that most of the things you just check algebraically.

So it would be nice to know if I can show that $B=B_1\oplus\dots\oplus B_n$ finding just splittings. Even more, obtaining in return projections on components with explicit formulas.

Btw. I know that I can do one splitting and then repeat the procedure for components, but maybe there is some sneaky way to grasp it globally.

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to get anything more useful than just iterating the case $n=2$.  The problem is that if you have only one of the maps for each $B_i$ (either the inclusion or the projection), then you need the splitting maps for all of them except one in order to construct the splitting map for the last one (if you're missing even just two of the splitting maps, you can't be sure that the last two maps do split).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the closest analogue I can see.  Suppose you have a finite set of objects $C_1,\dots C_n$, another object $B$, and maps $u_i:C_i\to B$ and $r_i:B\to C_i$ such that $r_iu_i=1_{C_i}$ for all $i$ and $r_ju_i=0$ for all $i\neq j$.  Let $q:A\to B$ be a kernel of the map $\sum u_ir_i:B\to B$.  Then there is a map $t:B\to A$ such that $tq=1_A$, and there is an isomorphism $B\cong A\oplus \bigoplus C_i$ that turns all of these maps into the inclusions and projections.  Furthermore, $t$ is obtained by simply factoring the map $1_B-\sum u_ir_i$ through $q$.

(This corresponds to the "left split" case of the splitting lemma; for the "right split" case, take a cokernel of $\sum u_ir_i$ instead of a kernel.)

Of course, if you let $C=\bigoplus C_i$, this is just a rehashing of the usual splitting lemma.   The hypotheses on the $r_i$ and $u_i$ say exactly that they combine to maps $r:B\to C$ and $u:C\to B$ such that $ru=1_C$, and the definition of $A$ says that we have an exact sequence $0\to A\to B\to C$.